# VB Case condition is true but, action is not executed

Tags: vb.net, select-case

I've write the following VB code.

```vb
Dim qu1, qu2, facroredload, bx, iterations, q3, err As Double
                
bx = 0.1
qu1 = "constant"

For iterations = 0 To 10000
    qu2 = "constant" * bx
    q3 = qu1 + qu2
    facroredload = "constant" / bx ^ 2
    err = Math.Abs(q3 - facroredload)

    Select Case err
        Case > 10
            bx += 0.1
        Case err <= 10 And err > 1
            bx = bx + 0.01
        Case err <= 1 And err > 0.1
            bx = bx + 0.001
        Case err <= 0.1 And err > 0.01
            bx = bx + 0.0001
        Case err < 0.01
            Exit For
    End Select
Next
```

`bx` value reaches 1.700000000004 (I don't know why the code adds too many decimals) and then it never changes. The `For` statement still exciting but, bx never goes beyond 1.7 even though `Case err <= 10 And err > 1` is true.

Comment: `err` is `Double`. `err <= 1 And err > 0.1` is `Boolean`. You cannot compare them. Turn `Option Strict On`. Alternatively, use `Select Case True` instead of `Select Case err`.

Comment: Turn on Option Strict. It can be annoying at first, but it will help you avoid this kind of error, and within a month you'll wonder how you ever did without it.

Comment: Also... for the "why too many decimals" problem, remember that `0.1` is a decimal representation of `1/10th`, whereas the computer will store this in binary. In binary, `1/10th` is a repeating value, similar to how `1/3rd` would in decimal. It's impossible to store accurately, and so whenever you use it you end up with small rounding errors creeping in.

Comment: Oh, and what do you expect the computer to do when multiplying a decimal with a string? That just makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VB's `Select Case` is really just a fancy if statement.  How each `Case` gets translated to an if expression depends on the format of the case expression.  There are three options:

- A range statement, like `Case 1 to 10`.  This translates to `If err >= 1 And err <= 10`.
- A statement that starts with a comparison operator, such as the `>` that begins your first `Case`.  When using this syntax, it just inserts your test expression before the case expression, as in `If err > 10`.
- A statement that is not a range and does not start with a comparison operator, such as your second `Case`.  This situation is treated exactly like the case with a comparison operator, where the comparison operator is implied to be `=`.  This means your second `Case` is treated as `If err = (err <= 10 And err > 1)`.

Once you understand this you should be able to see why your second `Case` statement doesn't work for you.  If `err` is 1.7, then the second case statement boils down to `If err = True`, but err is not True, it is a number between 1 and 10.

To fix your code you have a couple of options.  The simplest solution is this:

```
    Select Case err
        Case > 10
            bx += 0.1
        Case > 1
            bx = bx + 0.01
        Case > 0.1
            bx = bx + 0.001
        Case > 0.01
            bx = bx + 0.0001
        Case Else
            Exit For
    End Select
```

If more than one `Case` is satisfied, only the first satisfied clause will be executed, just like an `If/ElseIf`.  That's why the code above works even though it only specifies the lower bound of each range.  If you don't like the implied upper bound, you can add it like this: `Case > 1 And err <= 10`.  Personally I think it's actually clearer to leave off the upper bound of each range.